# An trick involving indicator variables, conditional probabilities and expepectation

Tags: conditional-probability, indicator-function

I am reading a paper on a statistical model for credit risk management. The details of the model are not important, but I mention for context.

Suppose that we are interested in a stochastic process $(A_t)_{t\in[0,T]}$ which has stationary and independent increments. Let $c$ be some fixed positive constant, from which we are interested in finding the conditional probability $P(A_{t_j}>c|A_T<0)$. The paper goes on to find this probability as follows.

$$ P(A_{t_j}>c|A_T<0) = \frac{P(A_{t_j}>c, A_T-A_{t_j}<-A_{t_j})}{P(A_T<0)}
$$
and here's the trick which I am having trouble justifying:
$$
P(A_{t_j}>c|A_T<0) = \frac{E[\boldsymbol{1}_{A_{t_j}>c}E[\boldsymbol{1}_{A_T-A_{t_j}<-A{t_j}}|A_{t_j}]]}{P(A_T<0)}.
$$

Can someone give me some insight into the origin of this identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation):
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(A_{t_j} > c, A_T - A_{t_j} < -A_{t_j})
&= E\left[\mathbf{1}_{\{A_{t_j} > c, A_T - A_{t_j} < -A_{t_j}\}}\right] \\
&= E\left[\mathbf{1}_{\{A_{t_j} > c\}}\mathbf{1}_{\{A_T - A_{t_j} < -A_{t_j}\}}\right] \\
&= E\left[E\left[\mathbf{1}_{\{A_{t_j} > c\}}\mathbf{1}_{\{A_T - A_{t_j} < -A_{t_j}\}}\,\middle|\, A_{t_j}\right]\right] \\
&= E\left[\mathbf{1}_{\{A_{t_j} > c\}} E\left[\mathbf{1}_{\{A_T - A_{t_j} < -A_{t_j}\}}\,\middle|\, A_{t_j}\right]\right].
\end{aligned}
$$
The second-to-last equality uses the law of total expectation, and the last equality uses the fact that $\mathbf{1}_{\{A_{t_j} > c\}}$ is $A_{t_j}$-measurable (so that it can be "pulled out" of the conditional expectation given $A_{t_j}$).